# Sort file using unix commands

Tags: awk, sed, sort

Input file:

```
tmp-1064,address3,state,country
tmp-1061,address1,state,country
tmp-1060,address2,state,country
tmp-106,address4,state,country
```

Current Output file

```
tmp-1060,address3,state,country
tmp-1061,address1,state,country
tmp-106,address2,state,country
tmp-1064,address4,state,country
```

Desired Ouptut File

```
tmp-106,address3,state,country
tmp-1060,address1,state,country
tmp-1061,address2,state,country
tmp-1064,address4,state,country
```

Comment: Do you know [Google](https://www.google.com/)?

Comment: @patrix sort won't work, i want the int value to be compared

Comment: @patrix yes I did, sort does char by char comparison. and compares the delimiter that is "," in this case

Comment: my example was wrong, see the updated one

Comment: @Cyrus could you answer this?

Comment: Sort on the 1st field only: `sort -t, -k1,1`

Comment: I suggest with GNU sort: `sort -V file`

Comment: @Cyrus thank you :) it worked! You add that as an answer!

Comment: @don_crissti it worked in certain cases, thanks though :)

Comment: I suggest you delete the question.

Comment: He doesn't need to delete the question(and downvoting it is a bit harsh) but for future reference, it is better that he learns from this that it is important to be clear on what he wants when asking a question to prevent this very thing and get the help he needs.

Comment: @NasirRiley appreciate your encouragement.

Comment: Can you please clarify: is `name` the exact same string of characters in every line, or can it be a different string of characters in every line?

Comment: Can the first field ever contain more than one hyphen, for example `Pall-Mall-111-1066`?

Comment: Can you show us the command you used to produce the current output file?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick "name-" in my case was a fixed string. I wanted to sort by number following it which would end at the delimiter ","

Answer (score 1):

Tell `sort` that your fields are delimited (`-t`) by commas and to use the first (-k1) field to sort, but only look at characters 5 and beyond of that field. Add the `n` sorting option to sort numerically:

```
sort -t, -k1.5n input
```

With GNU sort, you can watch it happen:

```
$ sort -t, -k1.5n --debug input
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
tmp-106,address4,state,country
    ___
______________________________
tmp-1060,address2,state,country
    ____
_______________________________
tmp-1061,address1,state,country
    ____
_______________________________
tmp-1064,address3,state,country
    ____
_______________________________
```

Comment: for me, sort -V worked well.

Comment: Great! Feel free to self-answer!

Comment: Cyrus has answered in the Qs' comments!

Comment: Comments aren't Answers, unfortunately.